# Return stock price based on stock name and date

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to be able to return a stock price based on stock ticker and date of my choosing

I have a number of stock with prices in columns B to H with prices underneath each stock ticker and dates on the left of the table.

I have attached a an image of the spreadsheet (below)

NOte that cells K1, L1 and J2 are input cells where I will decide which stock and which date I want to look at, and return prices (in cells K2 and L2) based on these parameters.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

*Stock prices table:*

[image: Stock prices table]

Answer (score 0):

The formula in K2:

```
=INDEX($A:$H,MATCH($J2,A:A,0),MATCH(K$1,1:1,0))
```

Copy over to the next column.